# VBA Evaluate - Match

Tags: excel, vba, match, evaluate

I have a problem with my codes below,
As you can see, I am trying to find the row value of a search. I have 3 different criteria ( they are defined before ) and 3 different ranges ( also defined before ). But I cannot find the rows unfortunately.

Here you can see the codes;

```
Gorev = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, o).Value
SlideNo = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 34).Value
Egitim_Adi = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(2, 3).Value
Check1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Range("A:A")   'Egitim_Adi Kontrolü için'
Check2 = Worksheets(j_WS).Range("B:B") 'SlideNo Kontrolü için'
Check3 = Worksheets(j_WS).Range("C:C")  'Gorev Kontrolü için'

Satir_bul = Evaluate("=Match(" & Egitim_Adi & " & " & SlideNo & " & " & Gorev & ", Check1 & Check2 & Check3, 0)")
```

I am open to any suggestion..

Comment: You need **Set** on the `Check1, Check2, Check3` statements

Comment: You need that row or row number? What is your main goal?

Comment: I just need the row number. Then I am going to use that number for another step.

Comment: can you add a column to j_WS? concatenate these 3 column in D and try match on it.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. Created a new column and concatenate 3 columns, but match function couldn't find the value. I double checked it with creating a MsgBox for match value ( which is " Egitim_Adi & SlideNo & Gorev " ) and it matches the newly created concatenate column. It should give the row number 3, but it didn't give anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a whole heap of problems there. `WorksheetFunction.Match` is not going to work because you are trying to replicate an array formula so `Evaluate` is definitely a better bet, but you need to construct the correct formula string for it. Unless you know whether the contents of the three cells will always be text or numbers, it is easier to just use cell addresses than to worry about enclosing the values in quotes:

```
Gorev = Cells(p, o).address
SlideNo = Cells(p, 34).address
Egitim_Adi = Cells(2, 3).address

Satir_bul = Worksheets(WS_All).Evaluate("=Match(" & Egitim_Adi & "&" & SlideNo & "&" & Gorev & ", '" & j_WS & "'!A:A&'" & j_WS & "'!B:B&'" & j_WS & "'!C:C, 0)")
```

If you can limit the ranges rather than using entire columns, you'll get better performance too.

Comment: @Bildircin13 Then you don't have a match and you presumably do have an error handler.

Comment: But I have a match, I wrote it myself just to be sure. :)

Comment: @Bildircin13 I tested the code and it works. Can you put a file somewhere showing it not working?

Comment: Rory, my deepest apologies, I didn't see the "address" change in your codes. Your code does work. Thank you so much really. :) :)

Comment: Hello Rory, unfortunately after the first loop of the codes (Next "p"), "Satir_bul" stucks at the first value.. Do you have any idea why it does something like that??

Comment: @Bildircin13 Best guess is you have something suppressing errors and you declared the variable as a non-Variant type.

Comment: I've used the "Satir_bul" as Long. When I change it to Variant, it messed up even worse :)

Comment: You should declare it as a `Variant` and then use `If Not IsError(Satir_bul) Then` so that you only proceed if you found a match.

Comment: Thank you so much man, this worked perfectly. I declared as variant and gave an else situation, now everything is great. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hello Rory, it's me again :) Do you have any idea how can I reset the "Satir_bul" at loops? Because after the first loop, if it was an error, it stucks at error and doesn't do anything unfortunately. I am using the ' If Not IsError(Satir_bul) ' as you said, and it's finding an error at first loop ( as it should do ) but it stucks at error and doesn't do anything after that I'm afraid.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `Evaluate` will always return a value, even if it's an error value, which will be assigned to the variable at each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Satir_bul = WorksheetFunction.Match ( Egitim_Adi & " & " & SlideNo & " & " & Gorev & ", Check1 & Check2 & Check3, 0)
```

[Here is a bit more about Match.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel)

It will not work. You should include Union of the ranges in Match. [Read more about Unions here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel)

Comment: It had a seperator problem so I used it like this;    <pre>Satir_bul = WorksheetFunction.Match(Egitim_Adi & " & " & SlideNo & " & " & Gorev, Check1 & Check2 & Check3, 0)<code>     But it didn't work either. Can there be a problem with ranges?? Because criterias are shown ok in F8 check.

Answer (score 0):

You have three strings `str1`, `str2`, `str3`. You have three search areas: `rng1`, `rng2` and `rng3`. Now, on every range you have to do the following (`cell` will be range variable):

```
For Each cell In rng1
  'here you determine if one of your strings is contained uisng InStr function
  'if the above condition is satisfied, then get the number of a row
Next cell
```

You'll do this then with `rng2` and `rng3`.